# PHP reg exp ignore word

Tags: php, regex

Trying to get a reg exp in PHP to work, I need it to match only if it doesn't start with a certain word.

Ex. Our ignore word will be "dave"

```
bill.smith <--- match<br/>
dave.smith <--- ignore<br/>
clyde.hancock <--- match<br/>
```

My current code is a bit of a mess, I'm not sure how to properly ignore with word boundaries (I hope I was on the right path??)

Anyways, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: any reason why you just can't use strpos?

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than what I've posted, I'm more or less just trying to figure out how I would ignore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `(?!...)` negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that:

```
preg_match('/^(?!dave\b)\w+\.\w+/', ...
```